# Slicing irregular spritesheet (automatically?)

Tags: sprites, spritesheet, texture-atlas

If found [a cool sprite sheet on the internet](https://opengameart.org/content/2d-lost-garden-zelda-style-tiles-resized-to-32x32-with-additions) but its irregular. [image]

Is there any way besides manually cutting sprites to extract the separate pngs?
I need to pack them then again into the Texture Atlas under proper names.

Maybe theres some smart online tool that uses deep learning or something like that?

Comment: This sheet looks like it's laid out on a regular grid. So, if you're OK having some objects placed as multiple tiles, you should be able to just split this using its grid frequency.

Comment: That sheet isn't irregular, it's 32x32 with some objects consisting of more than one tile. Source: I happened to work with this exact tileset before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the way, which is partially automated:

1. Open sprite sheet with Photoshop
2. Using the slice tool make one big slice that'll contain the entire image
3. Right-click it and split this slice into a grid (it's 32x32 pix I presume)
4. Join small slices into a bigger one (this have to be done by hand) where needed
5. Export every slice as a separate file using File -> Export As...

There are also online editors which allow you to do the same, like Photopea, but I'm afraid it can't slice image automatically. However, you can go to Edit -> Preferences... menu and make yourself a 32x32 pix guide-grid. Then you'll have to slice image manually, but it will be easier since each of slice rect borders will snap to grid lines.

Answer (score 3):

Since you found the picture online, without any `json` file attached or any other information, its not possible to cut this into multiple sprites automatically. You'd have to do it by hand.

Comment: Do you know any tool if Json and png exist?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Leshy's tools to split non uniform spritesheets: https://www.leshylabs.com/apps/sstool/

Your spritesheet is 32x32. I've used it before:

[image: OP's image with 32x32 px grid overlay]